# Sort object array by hour

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects with an hour(fc_start_time) property and I want to sort it by this property. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25621172/how-to-organize-a-javascript-object-that-contains-store-hours) but it does not work for me. 
This is the object structure:

```
Object { 
         id="540-events", 
         local_id=540, 
         title="Mas Flow", 
         fc_start_time="12:30 pm"
},
Object { 
         id="531-events", 
         local_id=531, 
         title="Slowly", 
         fc_start_time="04:30 pm"
},
Object { 
         id="531-events", 
         local_id=531, 
         title="Slowly", 
         fc_start_time="08:30 am"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting objects in an array by a field value in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1129216/710446)

Comment: apsillers, is the same concept, I didn't found it when research. However that solution doesn't work for my case. For example  '11:00 am' and '11:00 pm' are very similar and both will be before than "12:00 pm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this compare function according to the same time input as your example. It compares on the Floating notation of you time value.

```
<script>
    var objs = [
        {id:"540-events",local_id:540,title:"Mas Flow",fc_start_time:"12:30 pm"},
        {id:"540-events",local_id:540,title:"Mas Flow",fc_start_time:"10:30 pm"},
        {id:"540-events",local_id:540,title:"Mas Flow",fc_start_time:"12:30 pm"},
        {id:"540-events",local_id:540,title:"Mas Flow",fc_start_time:"14:30 pm"},
        {id:"540-events",local_id:540,title:"Mas Flow",fc_start_time:"09:30 pm"}
    ]       
    function compare(a,b) {
        var time1 = parseFloat(a.fc_start_time.replace(':','.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
        var time2 = parseFloat(b.fc_start_time.replace(':','.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
        if(a.fc_start_time.match(/.*pm/)) time1 += 12; if(b.fc_start_time.match(/.*pm/)) time2 += 12;
        if (time1 < time2) return -1;
        if (time1 > time2) return 1;
        return 0;
    }   
    objs.sort(compare);
    console.log(objs);      
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much,this work very well. Just one thing, what about if the array have an object with fc_start_time:"09:30 am" ?

Comment: You can add these checks:    if(a.fc_start_time.match(/.*pm/)) time1 += 12;
   if(b.fc_start_time.match(/.*pm/)) time2 += 12; just before the returns.

Answer (score 3):

Dates and time, eh? I hate them. Let's try to figure this out.

How you sort an array? With help of [array's sort method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). By default this method sorts strings, but we need custom compare function here.

How can we compare time in strings? We can use `Date` object, parse time, get milliseconds from 1970, and compare them. But we have `am-pm` format here. So, to use `Date.parse` method, we need to [convert time to 24 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083548/convert-12-hour-hhmm-am-pm-to-24-hour-hhmm) first (or use [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library).

```
function convertTo24Hour(time) {

  var hours = parseInt(time.substr(0, 2));

  if(time.indexOf('am') != -1 && hours == 12) {
    time = time.replace('12', '0');
  }
  if(time.indexOf('pm')  != -1 && hours < 12) {
    time = time.replace(hours, (hours + 12));
  }

  return time.replace(/(am|pm)/, '');
}
```

After we get 24h time, we can parse it like so (don't look at date before time, it doesn't matter, all we care about is time):

```
Date.parse( '9/19/2014 ' + convertTo24Hour(time) );
```

Now we can use this in `array.sort` compare function. We just compare two numbers, `1411129800000 ? 1411132800000`, decide which one is bigger and sort array.

```
function compare(a,b) {

  var atime = Date.parse('9/19/2014 ' + convertTo24Hour(a.time));
  var btime = Date.parse('9/19/2014 ' + convertTo24Hour(b.time));

  if (atime < btime) {
     return -1;
  }

  if (atime > btime) {
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What we got after all:

1. Use `array.sort` compare function to sort elements
2. Convert time to number so we can correctly compare them
3. To do so, convert 12h time format to 24 and use `Date.parse`

Here is jsfiddle to play with - http://jsfiddle.net/rqgmkdbs/

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = [{hour:1, minutes:10},{hour:4, minutes: 1}, ...];
input.sort(function (a, b)
{
    // compare hours first
    if (a.hour < b.hour) return -1;
    if (a.hour > b.hour) return 1;

    // else a.hour === b.hour, so compare minutes to break the tie
    if (a.minute < b.minute) return -1;
    if (a.minute > b.minute) return 1;

    // couldn't break the tie
    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You have to consider `am` and `pm` in your time.

```
<!doctype html>
</html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">      
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // The data
                var data = [
                   { id:"540-events", local_id:540, title:"Mas Flow", fc_start_time:"12:30 pm"}, 
                   { id:"531-events", local_id:531, title:"Slowly", fc_start_time:"04:30 pm"}, 
                   { id:"545-events", local_id:545, title:"Mas Flow 2", fc_start_time:"03:30 am"}
                ]
                // Sort values
                data.sort(function(a,b){
                    var aValue = new Number(a.fc_start_time.replace(/\d*/g,""));
                    var bValue = new Number(b.fc_start_time.replace(/\d*/g,""));
                    if( aTime.match(/.*pm/) ){
                        aValue + 12;
                    }
                    return aValue - bValue;    
                });
                // Show values
                for( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                    $("ul").append("<li>"+data[i].fc_start_time+"</li>");
                }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>        
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```